# FullCalendar : Change the background-color to all sundays

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I am struck up in my calendar page as i am newbie. I have to finish my
     project by keeping all the sundays with a back-ground color.    So now
     comes the question: Is there any way to manipulate the background of
     all sundays?
     After that i need to keep particular holidays in specific colors.
     I am sorry for my sick english. 
     I think there is a way.. Thanks a lot for every help u can give me! I 
    worked with jQuery and JS only a few hours till now.

**Here is my code that i tried**

```
  ` dayRender: function(date, cell) 
      {
        if (moment().diff(date,'days') > 0)
        {
              cell.css("background-color","silver");
        }    
        else
        { 
            cell.css("background-color","blue");
        }
       }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what actually you need but as far as I understood you want to change background color of all sundays, you can do this using css, try below css,

```
.fc-sun{ 
    color:#FFF; 
    background: red;
}
```

For ajax or jquery you need to do something like this

```
$('.fa-sun').css({'background':'red'});
```